# Jquery and iFrame update

Tags: jquery

I want to create a page that has a dropdown and an iframe, so that the iframe location will change based on the url in the dropdown. What is the correct syntax to get jquery to update the iframe's url?

thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think this will work:

```
$('#dropdownid').bind('change', function() {
    $('#iframeid').attr('src', $(this).val());
});
```

Answer (score 1):

To change an iframe's url, you update its src attribute.

Comment: This can be done with something like: `$(#iframe).attr('src', newURL);`