# changing iframe source with jquery

Tags: jquery

I've been trying this for a bit now and have looked at other answers to similar questions on SO, but when I am trying to change the src attribute of an iframe, it updates it for the whole window. Here is the following code I am using that works correctly (no jquery):

```
<html>
<head>
<style type="text/css">
iframe#ifrm { 
    border:none;
    padding:.5em;
    margin:1.5em 0 1em;
    width:100%;
    height:100%;
}
</style>
<script src="./js/jquery-1.4.2.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
// <![CDATA[
    // !!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!
    // this is the function I'm trying to replace:
    function loadIframe(iframeName, url) {
    if ( window.frames[iframeName] ) {
        window.frames[iframeName].location = url;   
        return false;
    }
    return true;
}
// ]]>
</script>
</head>

<body>
<ul>
<li><a href="http://www.google.com/" onclick="return loadIframe('ifrm', this.href)">Page 1</a> </li>
<li><a href="tabs.html" onclick="return loadIframe('ifrm', this.href)">Page 2</a></li>
</ul>
<div class="iframe">
<iframe name="ifrm" id="ifrm" src="tabs.html" frameborder="0">
Your browser doesn't support iframes.</iframe>
```

As I said, I've tried

```
$('#ifrm').attr('src', "http://www.google.com")
```

which displays the page, but not in the iframe. I'm really just learning jquery, but I can't figure out what's different about my situation than other similar questions like this:

[Jquery and iFrame update](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1477291/jquery-and-iframe-update)

Thanks.

Comment: You mention that it displays the page but not in the iframe, are you sure that's a jQuery issue and not a CSS problem?  Maybe you could enable borders to see if the frame is changing dimensions when it loads a new page.

Answer (score 145, accepted):

Should work.

Here's a working example:

http://jsfiddle.net/rhpNc/

Excerpt:

```js
function loadIframe(iframeName, url) {
    var $iframe = $('#' + iframeName);
    if ($iframe.length) {
        $iframe.attr('src',url);
        return false;
    }
    return true;
}
```

Comment: I have done like `$('[id*=iFrMap]').attr('src', link);`

Answer (score 2):

Using attr() pointing to an external domain may trigger an error like this in Chrome: "Refused to display document because display forbidden by **X-Frame-Options**". The workaround to this can be to move the whole iframe HTML code into the script (eg. using .html() in jQuery).

Example:

```
var divMapLoaded = false;
$("#container").scroll(function() {
    if ((!divMapLoaded) && ($("#map").position().left <= $("#map").width())) {
    $("#map-iframe").html("<iframe id=\"map-iframe\" " +
        "width=\"100%\" height=\"100%\" frameborder=\"0\" scrolling=\"no\" " +
        "marginheight=\"0\" marginwidth=\"0\" " +
        "src=\"http://www.google.it/maps?t=m&amp;cid=0x3e589d98063177ab&amp;ie=UTF8&amp;iwloc=A&amp;brcurrent=5,0,1&amp;ll=41.123115,16.853177&amp;spn=0.005617,0.009943&amp;output=embed\"" +
        "></iframe>");
    divMapLoaded = true;
}
```

Comment: does not work in IE 11 or FF 56 anymore (because of XSS rules) :(