# How to not display correct url in iframe src

Tags: html

I have this following code. When i do view source it displays my url in src. I don't want it displayed. Any tricks on not displaying the actual url in src but still show the right content in iframe

```
 <ice:panelGroup id="Success">
                 <iframe src="#{reqStatus.pdfURL}" width="820" height="400" ></iframe> 
            </ice:panelGroup>
```

When i do view source i can see this which i want to "hide" it if you will. If this is displayed then anyone can guess a number like 1235.pdf, 1236.pdf, etc..

```
<iframe height="400" src="http://myserver.com/MyApp/pdf/1234.pdf" width="820">
```

Answer (score 0):

You can set the src attribute via javascript instead of setting it in HTML.

See:
[changing iframe source with jquery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2930315/changing-iframe-source-with-jquery)