# How to change the src of an iframe with css

Tags: html, css, iframe

I have this code and idk how to make it so when I click on the items in the "menu" to not redirect to other pages but to change the src of the iframe.. should I change the

Code:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title> First attempt at html/css </title>
        <style>
            #header {
                background-color:black;
                color:white;
                text-align:center;
                padding:5px;
            }
            #menu {
                background-color:#eeeeee;
                height:470px;
                width:200px;
                float:left;
                text-align:center;
                padding:5px;
            }
            #content {
                float:left;
            }
            #footer {
                background-color:black;
                color:white;
                clear:both;
                text-align:center;
                padding:5px; 
            }
        </style>
    </head>

    <body>
        <div id="header">
        <h1> Movies Gallery</h1>
        </div>

        <div id="menu">
        <a href="the_maze_runner.html" style="text-decoration:none"> The Maze Runner </a> <br>
        <a href="guardians_of_the_galaxy.html" style="text-decoration:none"> Guardians of The Galaxy </a> <br>
        <a href="the_guest.html" style="text-decoration:none"> The Guest </a> <br>
        <a href="edge_of_tomorrow.html" style="text-decoration:none"> Edge of Tomorrow </a>
        </div>

        <div id="content">
        <iframe src="the_maze_runner.html" width=1110px height=475px frameborder=0></iframe>
        </div>

        <div id="footer">
        Copyright Andrew.Xd 2014
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

I'm still a starter in this domain so I really have no idea how should I modify the code to obtain what I intend to.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can simply add a **target** to your menu-items and a **name** to your iframe, like so:

```
<a target="frameName" href="the_maze_runner.html" style="text-decoration:none">The Maze Runner</a>

<iframe name="frameName" src="the_maze_runner.html" width=1110px height=475px frameborder=0></iframe>
```

Or did I missunderstand the question?

Answer (score 1):

css is a markup language, so you will not be able to do what you want with css.

However, you can give your iframe an id and change the source using javascript. [This SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2930315/changing-iframe-source-with-jquery) explains it perfectly, I could not do a better job :p

Answer (score 0):

If you have jQuery (you should!) then you can do something like this:

```
function Start() {

  $('#menu').click(function (e) {

      e.preventDefault();
      $('#content').find('iframe').prop('src', "whateverURL");
  });
}

$(Start);
```

Since you want to cancel the `href` in the `<a>` tags, why not remove them completely and replace them with `<div>` tags?

Comment: Firstly , this question is not marked under jQuery and title itself says that this question needs 'CSS' efforts .

Comment: @TusharRaj: well then show us how to do it in CSS:)

Comment: well might be it is not . But you must mention there so that the questioner knows that it can't be done in the way he is asking . You were not clear , sorry to say :)

Answer (score 0):

Its not Css code, its a JS code.

you need to to connect you items to an event listner take the href value on put it on the iframe
//jquery on load mathod//

```
  $(function(){
         $('#menu a').click(function(e){
              e.preventDefault();
              $('iframe ').attr('src',$(this).attr('href'));
         });
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't modify properties of DOM elements using css. Use js/jQuery:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#menu a").click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault(); //so browser will not follow link.
    $("#content iframe").attr("src", $(this).attr("href"));
  });
});
```

```css
#header {
  background-color: black;
  color: white;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 5px;
}
#menu {
  background-color: #eeeeee;
  height: 470px;
  width: 200px;
  float: left;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 5px;
}
#content {
  float: left;
}
#footer {
  background-color: black;
  color: white;
  clear: both;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 5px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id="header">
  <h1> Movies Gallery</h1>
</div>

<div id="menu">
  <a href="the_maze_runner.html" style="text-decoration:none"> The Maze Runner </a> 
  <br>
  <a href="guardians_of_the_galaxy.html" style="text-decoration:none"> Guardians of The Galaxy </a> 
  <br>
  <a href="the_guest.html" style="text-decoration:none"> The Guest </a> 
  <br>
  <a href="edge_of_tomorrow.html" style="text-decoration:none"> Edge of Tomorrow </a>
</div>

<div id="content">
  <iframe src="the_maze_runner.html" style="width:1110px; height:475px" frameborder=0></iframe>
</div>

<div id="footer">
  Copyright Andrew.Xd 2014
</div>
```