# Stop playing video iframe in a pure CSS modal when modal close

Tags: javascript, css, modal-dialog

I created a really simple [pure CSS modal](https://jsfiddle.net/a5q7xsr8/) on jsfiddle with an embed Youtube video `<iframe>` .

As this modal does not include any JS script, is still possible to stop playing the video on click on the close button? If yes can you give me a hint please?

I found this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40211944/stop-playing-video-in-iframe-when-modal-is-closed) but it did not helped me.

Many thanks in advance :)

Comment: basically no, but you can check this solution if you want to change your iframe src using css/html https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26102224/how-to-change-the-src-of-an-iframe-with-css

Comment: Does this answer your question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15164942/stop-embedded-youtube-iframe ?