# Replacing iframe URL after it has been inserted by JS

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, iframe

I'm trying to modify the src (domain name part) of an iframe on a clients website. The problem is that the iframe is generated by an external js file that I do not have access to.

My plan was to use inline jquery beneath the external js file to replace the iframe src after it has been generated, but this does not seem to be working.

What am I doing wrong here?

```
<html>
<head>
    <script src="/js/iframe_generate.js"></script>
    <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function() {
            $("#replace-1").attr("src").replace("ads.domain","www.domain");
        })
    </script>
</head>

<body>
    <div id="replace-1">
</body>
</html>
```

Note: The iframe_generate.js script replaces the div 'replace-1' with an iframe also with the id 'replace-1'.

My only thought is that the external JS replace happens after document is loaded and thus my jquery fires before the replacement has taken place?

Comment: *"My only thought is that the..."* that is very likely the case. without knowing what the iframe_generate.js does, we can't suggest a foolproof solution other than poor practice alternatives such as a setInterval or setTimeout recursion looking for the iframe.

Comment: This is only for the purpose of testing a theory and not for a live environment. I'd be really keen to hear how I can accomplish this with a recursion looking for the iframe in jquery.

Comment: you would simply start an interval, and on each interval look for the iframe. If found, stop the interval and change the src.

Comment: Do you have control over the contents of the iframe? If so, you may be able to use the `window.postMessage` protocol from the iframe to the parent window to know when the iframe is loaded. See [this](http://davidwalsh.name/window-iframe) reference.

Comment: see this one http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2930315/changing-iframe-source-with-jquery

Comment: Is their external js file dynamic? If not, you could just save it, make the needed modifications and serve it yourself.