# Process one function and then process another one automatically

Tags: javascript, html, ajax

I'm stuck here

```
<img src="img/server1.png" class="img-thumbnail servidor" data-url="https://google.com/"/>  

<div id="servidores-player">

  <iframe src="" id="player"></iframe>
  <div class="servidor-info">
    <div class="container">HD</div>
```

**JS 2ND UPDATED:**

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $(".servidor").on("click",function()  {
        $('.container > #servidores-bg').hide();
        $('#servidores-player').show();
        if ($("#player").length==0)
            $("#servidores-player").append($("<iframe/>",{id:"player‌​",src:$(this‌​).data‌​("url")); 
        else
            $("player").attr("src",$(this‌​).data("url")) });
        $('#servidores-player .servidor-info').show();
        var distance = $('#servidores-player iframe').offset().top
        $('html,body').animate({scrollTop:distance},1500);

    });
});


function mostrarServidores() {
    if (document.getElementById('inserido-utilizador')) {

        if (document.getElementById('inserido-utilizador').style.display == 'none') {
            document.getElementById('inserido-utilizador').style.display = 'block';
            document.getElementById('servidores-bg').style.display = 'none';
        }
        else {
            document.getElementById('inserido-utilizador').style.display = 'none';
            document.getElementById('servidores-bg').style.display = 'block';
        }
    }

}
```

Can someone help me to just create de `<iframe>` tag when I click in the image? And jump to iframe element before it loads?

I already updated the codeuntil the part that i'm getting error

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please update your question with expected output and actual output. It is not clear what you want to happen

Comment: Yes its clear, i would like to create the <iframe> tags only when I click in server images and open the link that u put on: onlick=""...

Comment: but... I would like to get the source from `onClick='` is it possible?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Creating an iframe with given HTML dynamically](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10418644/creating-an-iframe-with-given-html-dynamically)

Comment: @AniketSinha poor duplicate not using jQuery

Comment: @AniketSinha it's different because I want to create the tag only when the user clicks on the image..

Comment: Wrap up the code in a function , and call the function when user clicks the image. With slight modification, you can achieve it w/o even using jQuery.

Comment: @mplungjan it's not working, when i insert it, the rest of the script doesn't work

Comment: @mplungjan I already updated the js

Comment: It's not working, could u help me by teamviewer?

Comment: What does the console say?????

Comment: stills not working, could u come by teamviewer because its better to explain to you :/ @mplungjan

Comment: @mplungjan `main.js:5 Uncaught SyntaxError: Invalid or unexpected token
VM22764 filme.php:263 Uncaught ReferenceError: mostrarServidores is not defined`

Comment: 821 488 554 5945 @mplungjan

Comment: www.teamviewer.com @mplungjan

Comment: i really need help, i'll update my code

Comment: UPDATED @mplungjan

Comment: stills http://prntscr.com/c9e1z4 @mplungjan

Comment: Please note the code from the comment had invisible characters added to it

Answer (score 1):

1. you need to replace the iframe if the content is not from the same origin as the page you are on.
2. some URLs like google and stackexchange cannot be loaded into an iframe
3. Use data- attribute for the URL

```js
$(function() {
  $(".servidor").on("click", function() {
    $('#servidores-bg').hide(); // IDs must be unique
    $("#player").replaceWith(
      $("<iframe/>", {
        id: "player",
        src: $(this).data("url")
      })
    );
    $('#servidores-player .servidor-info').show();
    var distance = $('#servidores-player iframe').offset().top;
    $('html,body').animate({
      scrollTop: distance
    }, 1500);
    $('#servidores-player').show();
  });
});


function mostrarServidores() {
  var $inser = $('#inserido-utilizador');
  if ($inser.length) {
    $inser.toggle();
    $('#servidores-bg').toggle($inser.is(":visible"));
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<img src="img/server1.png" class="img-thumbnail servidor" data-url="http://api.jquery.com/replacewith/" />
<img src="img/server1.png" class="img-thumbnail servidor" data-url="http://api.jquery.com/toggle/" />

<div id="servidores-player">
  <iframe src="" id="player"></iframe>
  <div class="servidor-info">
    <div class="container">
      HD
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to set the iframe src use:

```
$('#player').attr('src', $(this‌​).data('url'));
```

And to scroll to it:

```
$('html, body').animate({scrollTop: $("#player").offset().top}, 2000);
```

-

Comment: I have already posted that piece of code twice in the comments

Comment: So you just downvote people who give the correct answer rather than create your own answer which wouldn't be buried in comments people might not have read?

Comment: There is no answer yet because he has not yet asked the correct question. Your answer is not answering his issue which is way more complex than setting the src. For example you cannot set the src more than once if the url is not same origin as the page with the iframe. I have not had time to write a proper answer.

Comment: If that is the case then he can do so by replacing the entire iframe code via html() and then scroll to it. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2930315/changing-iframe-source-with-jquery

Comment: And your scroll code is identical to what he already had. So the downvote is for not sufficiently answering the question and not adding anything new to the discussion- I can remove the down vote but that is the reason