# Modify a code snippet and print the result

Tags: javascript, php, html, forms

I'm a web designer but i'm starting to learn some coding.
Probably this question may seem very basic, but I've been pulling my hear out trying to figure out where to begin.
I want to build a small tool for myself that can replace several values in a chunk of code at once.

Let's say I have this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head></head>
<body>
<iframe src="about:blank" id="myiframe" style="display:none;"></iframe>
</body>
</html>
```

I want to build a form where I can type the values I need to change, submit and then print the resulting code. In this example I'd need to replace `about:blank` and `myiframe`.

The printed result must be:

```
<iframe src="myNewValue" id="anotherNewValue" style="display:none;"></iframe>
```

What would be the best way to proceed?

Comment: Welcome to [so]! Looks like you need to learn more about what is expected of users here. You're expected to try to **write the code yourself**. After [doing more research](//meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592) if you have a problem you can **post what you've tried** with a **clear explanation of what isn't working** and providing a [**Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example**](//stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). I suggest reading [ask] a good question and [the perfect question](http://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/). Also, be sure to take the [tour].

Comment: Possible duplicate of [changing iframe source with jquery](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2930315/changing-iframe-source-with-jquery)

Comment: as you are a web designer, I'm surprised you don't know about the following elements `<form>`, `<input>`, `<textbox>` and perhaps `<button>` and `<select><option>` - these are the very basic building blocks of a form that you require

Answer (score 0):

Hey I think this should do it. No PHP necessary just make a Javascript function like below; and if you want this to run when a button is clicked or something just say onclick="changey()"

```
    <script>
function changey() {
        document.getElementById('myiframe').src = 'myNewValue';
        document.getElementById("myiframe").setAttribute("id", "div_top2");
}
    </script>
```