# How to change url in a div element, which is loaded by iframe with javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, iframe, google-chrome-extension

In my manifest.json:

```
"content_scripts": [
        {
        "matches": [
            "http://*/*",
            "https://*/*"
            ],
        "css":["style.css"],
        "js": ["./js/jquery-3.3.1.js","content-script.js", "./search-api/search-api.js"],
        "run_at": "document_end"
        }
    ],
```

In content-script.js

```
var height = "40px";
var iframe = document.createElement("iframe");
iframe.src = chrome.extension.getURL("toolbar.html");
iframe.style.height = height;
iframe.style.width = "100%";
iframe.style.position = "fixed";
iframe.style.top = "0";
iframe.style.left = "0";
iframe.style.zIndex = "938089"; // Some high value
// Etc. Add your own styles if you want to
document.documentElement.appendChild(iframe);

// continuing add-toolbar.js
var bodyStyle = document.body.style;
var cssTransform = 'transform' in bodyStyle ? 'transform' : 'webkitTransform';
bodyStyle[cssTransform] = 'translateY(' + height + ')';
```

toolbar.html:

```
<div style="color:aqua">
    <a target="_blank" href="https://www.uber.com" id="toolbars">Uber cool home page</a>
</div>
```

This loads up the iframe into my webpage fine. But I want to dynamically change the url of the link. Let's say I want to change it to amazon.com from uber.com.

Tried:

```
iframe.find('toolbars').href("www.amazon.com")
```

Comment: using jquery or without?

Comment: Try this: `$('#toolbars', parent.document).attr ('href', 'www.amazon.com');`

Comment: jquery, ofcourse :)

Comment: @wayneOS what does parent.document do? I would like to know what it is referring to.

Comment: @kai sorry i got you wrong. what you need is `$('iframe').contents ().find ('#toolbars').attr ('href', 'www.amazon.com');`. parent.document would be needed to change things in the parent-window out of the iframe-context.

Comment: Thanks @wayneOS, that worked.

Comment: @kai You're welcome. I added it as an answer for completion. Would you mind accepting it?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [changing iframe source with jquery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2930315/changing-iframe-source-with-jquery)

Answer (score 0):

The Simplest way to do this is to use JavaScript or jquery.

1. JavaScript:

   `document.getElementById("toolbars").setAttribute("href", "www.amazon.com");`
2. JQuery:

   `$('#toolbars').attr('href', 'www.amazoncom');`

Answer (score 0):

To access an element in an imbedded iframe you first need to access it [contents()](https://api.jquery.com/contents/) and then use [find()](https://api.jquery.com/find/) to get it elements. In your case that would look like:

```
$('iframe').contents ().find ('#toolbars').attr ('href', 'www.amazon.com');
```

Answer (score -1):

You can do like this.

```
$(‘#iframID’).attr(‘src’,’your url’);
```

There is a perfect answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2930516/4156974).