# Jquery LOAD as alternative or similar to IFRAME

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, url, iframe

I have jquery to load user messages every 1 second but I would like to implement a solution to the messages load to act, similar as a: `<iframe>`, `<object>` or `<embed>` tags

```
<script>
setInterval(
function()
{
$('#chat').load('load_chat.php');
}, 1000);
</script>
```

The problem is as it loads every 1 second I can't just use a iframe of the page, I need to keep using jquery, somebody has a solution?

I tried with:

```
<script>
setInterval(
function()
{
//$('#chat').load('load_chat.php');
$("#frame").attr("src", "load_chat.php");

}, 1000);
</script>
```

But this is not what I need, it flash the iframe all the time.

I need to make `jquery load` method looks like a iframe.
but the problem with using iframe is because I need jquery to refresh the frame every 1 second. some body has an idea of how to make `<div id="chat"></div>` have a scroll bar as iframe ?

Comment: Possible duplicate to issue [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2930315/changing-iframe-source-with-jquery)

Comment: It's not duplicated please read me question I don't need change the iframe source I write also a example on my code, I need an alternative to iframe using jquery, I need to make jquery load method looks like a iframe.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved with the following:

```
$('#chat').css("overflow-y", "scroll");
```

If someone has a better alternative it would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

First off all I think this is not the correct way to do this.
Read up on streams, because this type of use case is exactly what they where made for.

Then, if you have your load-chat.php loaded in an iframe, you can use the window send message method to trigger a reloadin the page by jquery.
The downside is, that your iframe should also contain a jquery instance.

Check this -> https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/postMessage

Comment: yeah, the problem with load as iframe it's because I need jquery loading the page every1 second and if I load inside an iframe it makes the iframe scroll bar flash all the time.

Comment: do you have an idea of how to make `<div id="chat"></div>` act like a iframe ?