# Play video in a seperate div on link click

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

I'm trying to play a video on a seperate div on link click but whenever I click the link instead of playing inside the div it plays on full screen and the link changes to the file path.

```js
$('.link').on('click', function(event) {
   event.preventDefault();
   var url =$(this).attr("href");
   $("#frame").attr("src", url);
})
```

```html
<div class="live1452">
  <iframe allow="accelerometer; autoplay; encrypted-media; gyroscope; picture-in-picture" allowfullscreen id="frame"></iframe>
</div>

<div class="title">
  <a href="{{l.file.url}}" class="text-normal link">{{l.title}}</a>
</div>
```

Comment: Take a look here:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2930315/changing-iframe-source-with-jquery

Comment: It seems like your script ain't working, maybe try event delegation `$('body').on('click', '.link', function(event){ ... })`

Answer (score 1):

It seems as if it following the link, it shouldn't as you are calling event.preventDefault(), if there were other events wrapping that one you should have to also call event.stopPropagation() but we lack information to know if this could be the case.

I would not use iframe for this, you could try using the [html5 video element](https://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_video.asp) instead, here is a code snippet:

```js
$('.link').on('click',function(event) {
   event.preventDefault();
   event.stopPropagation();
   var url =$(this).attr("href");
   $("#video").attr("src", url);
   $("#video")[0].play();
});
```

```css
video {
   width: 300px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="live1452">
    <video controls allow="accelerometer; autoplay; encrypted-media; gyroscope; picture-in-picture" allowfullscreen id="video"></video>
</div>

<div class="title">
    <a href="https://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/video/basics/devstories.mp4" class="text-normal link">Sample video</a>
</div>
```